# compile c++ program in yocto

Tags: c++, yocto, bitbake

I have followed a tutorial to include a C program in my yocto image. It worked like a charm and now I have a helloworld script running on my machine.

I want to do the same with c++ because I need to load a program which makes use of opencv.

I tried by changing c with cpp but as I though, it failed. what else do I need to change to make this working? 
Can you point me to any tutorial or example out there? I haven't been able to find a suitable one with a simple example.

Comment: you dont turn a c code into c++ code by simply changing the file extension

Comment: I know, that's why I am asking about how to modify the compile order on the recipe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume that you follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HsaoVqX7dg) on creating `helloWorld.bb` and `meta-mylayer`

This is how you would compile a C++ file in Yocto:

First you need to understand what the GNU compiler and build flag option in Yocto;  In `bspdir/sources/poky/meta/conf/bitbake.conf` There is a list of compilers which bitbake uses to cross compile:

```
TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS = " --sysroot=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}"

export CC = "${CCACHE}${HOST_PREFIX}gcc ${HOST_CC_ARCH}${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}"
export CXX = "${CCACHE}${HOST_PREFIX}g++ ${HOST_CC_ARCH}${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}"
export FC = "${CCACHE}${HOST_PREFIX}gfortran ${HOST_CC_ARCH}${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}"
export CPP = "${HOST_PREFIX}gcc -E${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS} ${HOST_CC_ARCH}"
export LD = "${HOST_PREFIX}ld${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS} ${HOST_LD_ARCH}"
export CCLD = "${CC}"
export AR = "${HOST_PREFIX}ar"
export AS = "${HOST_PREFIX}as ${HOST_AS_ARCH}"
export RANLIB = "${HOST_PREFIX}ranlib"
export STRIP = "${HOST_PREFIX}strip"
export OBJCOPY = "${HOST_PREFIX}objcopy"
export OBJDUMP = "${HOST_PREFIX}objdump"
export STRINGS = "${HOST_PREFIX}strings"
export NM = "${HOST_PREFIX}nm"
PYTHON = "${@sys.executable}"

export BUILD_CC = "${CCACHE}${BUILD_PREFIX}gcc ${BUILD_CC_ARCH}"
export BUILD_CXX = "${CCACHE}${BUILD_PREFIX}g++ ${BUILD_CC_ARCH}"
export BUILD_FC = "${CCACHE}${BUILD_PREFIX}gfortran ${BUILD_CC_ARCH}"
export BUILD_CPP = "${BUILD_PREFIX}gcc ${BUILD_CC_ARCH} -E"
export BUILD_LD = "${BUILD_PREFIX}ld ${BUILD_LD_ARCH}"
export BUILD_CCLD = "${BUILD_PREFIX}gcc ${BUILD_CC_ARCH}"
export BUILD_AR = "${BUILD_PREFIX}ar"
export BUILD_AS = "${BUILD_PREFIX}as ${BUILD_AS_ARCH}"
export BUILD_RANLIB = "${BUILD_PREFIX}ranlib"
export BUILD_STRIP = "${BUILD_PREFIX}strip"
export BUILD_NM = "${BUILD_PREFIX}nm"

export MAKE = "make"
EXTRA_OEMAKE = "-e MAKEFLAGS="
EXTRA_OECONF = ""
export LC_ALL = "C"
```

Execute `bitbake -e | grep CXX` , you will see where the toolchain is directly pointed to.

```
export CXX="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -marm  -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/mountdata/charles/hio-yocto-bsp/jethro/build/tmp/sysroots/hio-imx6dl-board"
```

Now, understood where the toolchain background, we will use `CXX` to compile helloworld recipe;

Change `meta-mylayer/recipes-example/example/helloworld-0.1/helloworld.c` to `helloworld.cpp`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello World "<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and modify `helloworld.bb`. take note that I have changed from `{CC}` to `{CXX}` and the `helloworld.c` changed to `helloworld.cpp`

```
SUMMARY = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.cpp"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
         ${CXX} helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Now you can use `bitbake helloworld` to create the package.